# Does RPi 3 have BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy/Bluetooth 4.0/Bluetooth Smart)

Tags: python

I am wondering if the RPi3 has BLE built in.  (Not standard bluetooth, but BLE)

And if it does, how do I find BLE devices or install BLE software or whatever, as I know Raspbian doesn't support BLE itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [datasheet](http://www.cypress.com/documentation/datasheets/bcm43438-single-chip-ieee-80211-bgn-macbasebandradio-bluetooth-41-and-fm) of the Raspberry Pi 3's BCM43438 radio chip (emphasis mine):

> a 2.4 GHz WLAN IEEE 802.11 b/g/n MAC/baseband/radio, **Bluetooth 4.1**
>   **support**, and an FM receiver.

Adafruit have a [great tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/install-bluez-on-the-raspberry-pi/overview) on installing the latest version of [BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org/) (the official Linux Bluetooth protocol stack). They summarise the process as:

- [Download source](http://www.bluez.org/download/)
- Install dependencies

  - `sudo apt-get update`
  - `sudo apt-get install -y libusb-dev libdbus-1-dev libglib2.0-devlibudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev`
- Compile and install BlueZ
- Set up BlueZ service

  - `sudo systemctl start bluetooth`
  - `systemctl status bluetooth`
  - `sudo systemctl stop bluetooth`
- Enable Bluetooth Low Energy features

  - Edit `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service` to enable experimental features
  - Restart BlueZ service

Once all that's done you can use [bluetoothctl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth#Bluetoothctl) to scan for nearby BLE devices.

While it's not explicitly mentioned in your question, the `python` tag implies that you might get some use out of the [pybluez module](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez), a 'Python extension module allowing access to system Bluetooth resources.'